# Slice() Not working on 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I'm trying to copy a 2D array by value using slice() so when I change my new array it won't affect the original. However, it seems to be working on a 1 dimensional array but not on a 2 dimensional.

Here is my code:

```js
var arrayA = new Array(5); // Make 2d array
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arrayA[i] = new Array(5);
}
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) { // Populate original array
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayA[x][i] = x + i;
  }
}
arrayB = arrayA.slice(); // make new array 1
arrayB[0][0] = 10;
var arrayC = arrayA.slice(); // make new array 2 (wanted to see it changed when I use var)
arrayC[0][0] = 100; // Changing value of 1st element of last array


$(document).click(function() {
  alert(arrayA[0][0]); // Prints 100
  alert(arrayB[0][0]); // Prints 100
  alert(arrayC[0][0]); // Prints 100
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me why slice isn't working with a multi dimensional array and if there is anyway to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.slice` copied the individual array references instead of doing a deep copy. You can use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to achieve your need:

```js
var arrayA = new Array(5); // Make 2d array
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arrayA[i] = new Array(5);
}
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) { // Populate original array
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayA[x][i] = x + i;
  }
}
arrayB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayA));
arrayB[0][0] = 10;
var arrayC = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayA));
arrayC[0][0] = 100; // Changing value of 1st element of last array


$(document).click(function() {
  alert(arrayA[0][0]); // Prints 0
  alert(arrayB[0][0]); // Prints 10
  alert(arrayC[0][0]); // Prints 100
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will I need to parse all the values in the new arrays back to Integers since I'm using stringify?

Comment: no, JSON supports numbers, strings, boolean and null, but if you have in your array something like `[1, 2, 3, undefined, 5]` you should aware that `undefined` will be turned to `null`. same with `Infinity` and `-Infinity`

Comment: @MarksCode. no need. `.stringify` translates `[1,2,3]` to `"[1,2,3]"` and `.parse` brings it back to `[1,2,3]`

Comment: When I do JSON.stringify(arrayA) does my arrayA change or is it the same as it was? If so how do I change it back? Thanks.

Comment: it does not change arrayA. if you run the code in my answer, it alerts 0, 10, 100. sorry I forgot to update the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is because arrayA[0] is a link to array, not array itself, so

`arrayB[0][0] = 10;` and `arrayC[0][0] = 100;` changes same array, you need to clone inner array if you need to change it's fields idepended:

```
var a = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]
var b = a.slice();
var c = a.slice();
b[0]=b[0].slice();
c[0]=c[0].slice();
b[0][0] = 10
c[0][0] = 100

console.log(a[0][0], b[0][0], c[0][0]);
```

usually if you need deep clone, it is better to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));`